# What's wrong with this OCaml code?

Tags: ocaml, syntax-error, if-statement

What's wrong with this code?

```
let vm_run vm =
    let guard = ref true in
    while !guard do
        if vm.cur_pc = -1 && not (Stack.empty vm.call_stack) then vm_pop_ar vm
        else if vm.cur_pc = -1 then guard := false
        else if vm.cur_pc < Array.length vm.cur_code then
            execute vm Array.get vm.cur_code vm.cur_pc;
            vm.cur_pc <- vm.cur_pc + 1
        else vm_pop_ar vm
    done
```

Error is `Error: Syntax error` related to the last `else` keyword.

I reached good confidence with OCaml but an if/else chain still gives me some troubles.. that's not the first time (last time I exploited flow to avoid using the else keyword).

I think it's something small but have no clues, according to syntax specification it should be ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semicolon has lower precedence than if-else, so when you need to have a block of two or more statements separated by semicolons inside an `if`, you need to enclose them in parentheses or a `begin...end` block (the two are equivalent):

```
    else if vm.cur_pc < Array.length vm.cur_code then begin
        execute vm Array.get vm.cur_code vm.cur_pc;
        vm.cur_pc <- vm.cur_pc + 1
    end
    else vm_pop_ar vm
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a difficult one :)
So it tried to parse ending the if body before the intended end finding the `else` unpaired.. silly thing. Now it's clear!