# Syntax error with if-then-else statement?

Tags: if-statement, syntax-error, ocaml

I'm making an algorithm in OCaml (which is supposed to print a pyramid). However, I've run into a syntax error with my if-then-else statement: the first `else` triggers a syntax error. It's probably a stupid mistake on my part but I can't solve it for the life of me.

```
let rec build_line_pyramid m n (a,b) = 
  if m >= m/2 then print_string (a) ; build_line_pyramid (m - 1) n (a,b)
  else if n = 0 then print_string (b) ; build_line_pyramid m (n - 1) (a,b)
    else if m >= 0 then print_string (a) ; build_line_pyramid (m - 1) n (a,b)
      else print_newline ()
```

Comment: And also: [What's wrong with this OCaml code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183020/whats-wrong-with-this-ocaml-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should parenthesis your statement

```
print_string (a) ; build_line_pyramid (m - 1) n (a,b)
```

like

```
( print_string (a) ; build_line_pyramid (m - 1) n (a,b) )
```

because your trailing ';' take precedence over your 'else' statement. Thus closing your if statement.

Comment: Or we can enclose them inside a `begin ... end` block.